# How can I save buttons in variable, created by Element.insertAdjacentHTML() method?

Tags: javascript

as I said in title I have problem with HTML elements created with Element.insertAdjacentHTML() method, I'm trying about an hour to solve this but can't. I have button that create new HTML elements, couple of that elements is new buttons with same class or id, it's no matter, that I need to catch in some variable and than again use for event listener, for some reason the class or id for these new created button doesn't exist, is there any way to catch it and use it later, I need Vanila Javascript?

There is over 500 lines of code, this is only for mentioned method

```
btnClaim.addEventListener("click", () => {
    rewardCurrent.style.display = "none";
    claimedRewards.push(currentReward);
    rewardsList.innerHTML = ``;

    claimedRewards.forEach(function (rew, i) {
      const html = `
    <div class="reward" id="${i}">
      <div class="img-text-cont">
        <img src="${rew.imgUrl}" alt="">
        <div class="text-cont">
          <p class="claimed-reward-title">${rew.title}</p>
          <p class="claimed-reward-price">$${rew.price}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="claimed-rewards-action">
        <button id="btn-sell2">Sell</button>
        <button id="btn-ship">Ship</button>
      </div>
    </div>
      `;

      rewardsList.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
```

I need that btn-sell2 and btn-ship buttons in variables.

Comment: Please show the code. How do you add these listeners? Every element has to have unique id

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i edit post with code, i have event listener that with for clicks create four different products, and all that products have same two buttons sell and ship with same class and id and i need all sell buttons in one variable and all ship buttons in one variable, i tried with querySelectorAll but node list is empty

Comment: You have to use `querySelectorAll` and add event listeners to these buttons

Comment: if your element "is going to" be created and doesn't exist at the time page loads, you'll see the error, to solve you have to addeventlistener to element inside the function that is creating the element

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i tried, but dont work, node list is empty

Comment: @IsoW i tried but node list is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your element is going to be created and doesn't exist at the time page loads, so js addeventlistener will throw an error. to solve you have 2 ways.

1- use parent node that element will be created inside.
addevenlistener to parent and use

```
parent.addeventlistener( event, function (event){
    if(event.target.classList.contains("childClass") {}
}
```

2- give addeventlistener when creating the element :

```
function createElement () {
  const elem = -craete elemnt-
  elem.addeventlistener(event, function);
}
```